# How to upload the image using ajax with jquery validation in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, ajax and jquery validation. I am uploading the profile pic but it's not working.

If I upload an image without jquery validation then it's working but with jquery validation, it's not working. It displays the If condition

```
if ($this - > form_validation - > run() == FALSE) {
        echo "Not working";
      }
```

It's not sending the image name from ajax to controller. I added the server side validation and it's displaying the error `"The Profile Pic field is required."` Would you help me out with this issue?

**View**

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="edit_Memberdetails" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="profile_pic" id="profile_pic">
<?php echo form_error('profile_pic'); ?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edit_Memberdetails").validate({
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
      profile_pic: {
        required: true,
        extension: "jpg,jpeg,png"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var formData = new FormData(form);
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Member_controller/edit_Memberdetails');?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Added successfully");
          setTimeout(function() { // wait for 5 secs(2)
            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
          }, 1000);
        },
      }); // AJAX Get Jquery statment
    }

  });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function edit_Memberdetails() {
  $this - > form_validation - > set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
  $this - > form_validation - > set_rules('profile_pic', 'Profile Pic', 'required');

  if ($this - > form_validation - > run() == FALSE) {
    echo "Not working";
  } else {
    $config = [
      'upload_path' => './uploads/images',
      'allowed_types' => 'jpg|png|jpeg',
      'file_name' => uniqid().time().date("dmy")
    ];

    print_r($config);
    $this - > load - > library('upload', $config);
    if ($this - > upload - > do_upload('profile_pic')) {
      $profile_pic_set = $this - > upload - > data('file_name');
    }

    $data = array(
      'profile_pic' => $profile_pic_set
    );
    $secure_data = $this - > security - > xss_clean($data);
    if ($secure_data) {
      $this - > db - > where('customer_id', $this - > session - > userdata['login_session']['custid']);
      $this - > db - > set($secure_data);
      $this - > db - > update('members', $secure_data);
      $this - > session - > set_flashdata('success', "recode added");

    } else {
      $this - > session - > set_flashdata('error', "Sometning wrong! please check the internet connection and try again");
    }
    // redirect("Member_controller/member_dashboard");//calling employee register 
  }

}
```

Comment: use ajaxForm that is  easy.

Comment: @DhruvRaval, Can you share some more information?

Comment: you nedd to use `jquery.form.js`

Comment: @user9437856 you may found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648438/upload-file-using-ajax-and-php/53649518#53649518) , this code not for `codeigniter` but shows `ajax` code to get image details and send it to `php` page to upload.

Comment: @saddam, Thanks for the link, That is not my issue, my code is also working but the issue is when I am using jquery validation then it's not working.

Comment: I think you just missed a validation jquery file, use this `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>` at top of your script code.

Comment: @saddam, I already added plugin links in the view. I know I haven't added in the question.

Comment: @user9437856 try with removing rules content `extension: "jpg,jpeg,png"`.

Comment: Yes, I did but the same issue. I am getting the issue on  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){ } because it's always calling the if conditon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image uploading via ajax you have to manually append image to `FormData` so change your code little bit as following in your `submitHandler:`

```
var formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('edit_Memberdetails'));

var profile_pic = $('#profile_pic').get(0).files[0];

formdata.append('profile_pic', profile_pic);
```

File upload data is not stored in the **$_POST array**, so cannot be validated using CodeIgniter's **form_validation library**. File uploads are available to PHP using the **$_FILES array** so change form validation rule in Your **Controller**, :

```
$this-> form_validation->set_rules('profile_pic', 'Profile Pic', 'required');
```

To this :

```
if (empty($_FILES['profile_pic']['name']))
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('profile_pic', 'Profile picture', 'required');
}
```

Comment: It's refreshing the page after adding your code. It's not working

Comment: @user9437856 Try to `print_r($_FILES);exit;` in your controller for testing whether you are getting file or not.

Comment: ,I added the code before If condition and I am getting the name but it's calling the if condition only. it's not calling the else condition.

Comment: @user9437856 ,  you can do `if (!empty($_FILES['profile_pic']['name'])) {` instead of set_rules('profile_pic') for file is empty or not.

Comment: I have more than 8 fields and I am testing only one field for now. Every field is proper validation using jquery.

Comment: @user9437856 for only file input you have to set_rules differently see another stackoveflow answer about how to set validation on file input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12289225/codeigniter-file-upload-required-validation

Comment: Yes, that link resolved my issue. I tried    if (empty($_FILES['profile_pic']['name'])){$this->form_validation->set_rules('profile_pic', 'Document', 'required');
 } and it's working. but my set_rules not working without if condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185034/discussion-between-haritsinh-gohil-and-user9437856).

Answer (score 0):

Append image to form data e.g:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var files = $('#file')[0].files[0]; 
fd.append('file',files);
```

[full example here](http://makitweb.com/how-to-upload-image-file-using-ajax-and-jquery/)

Comment: I think, there is some issue with my jquery  because it's not sending the file name to the controller

Comment: you need to append file. check example